# How do I create a specific nesting format JSON or dictionary from a pandas dataframe using vectorized operations?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, nested

I am attempting to make an API call. For this specific API, one of the keys in the JSON file needs to have a nested dictionary inside of it.

here is the input data in dataframe format:

```
ID        Date        Total_Transactions   Amount    Account_Name__c
1234567   2022-12-21  1                    235.00    a1234567
2345678   2022-13-21  2                    300.50    a2345678
```

The end result needs to look like this with a key "Account_Name__r" outside of the nested dictionary:

```
[{'ID': '1234567',
  'Date': '2022-12-21',
  'Total_Transactions': 1,
  'Amount': 235.00,
  'Account_Name__r': {'Account_Name__c':'a1234567'}},
{'ID': '2345678',
  'Date': '2022-13-21',
  'Total_Transactions': 2,
  'Amount': 300.50,
  'Account_Name__r': {'Account_Name__c':'a2345678'}}]
```

The data is coming from a data frame. I can get a normal data frame to export properly, but having issues with the nesting.
Here's what it looks like when I do the normal dataframe as a normal json:

code:

```
final.to_json(orient='records')
```

output:

```
[{'ID': '1234567',
  'Date': '2022-12-21',
  'Total_Transactions': 1,
  'Amount': 235.00,
  'Account_Name__c':'a1234567'},
{'ID': '2345678',
  'Date': '2022-13-21',
  'Total_Transactions': 2,
  'Amount': 300.50,
  'Account_Name__c':'a2345678'}]
```

Any ideas how i need to structure my dataframe and what transformations/functions I need to use to get the nested structure I have at the top? I am looking to achieve this by performing vectorized operations in pandas and by using the df.to_json() method in pandas.

I am not looking for a for loop solution, that is easy but does not actually help me learn how to create different kinds of complex JSON structures from a pandas dataframe and in my case is not scalable for the large datasets I'll be using.

Comment: Please share the input data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by breaking this down into a smaller problem to solve. I posted the question here: [Is there a way to store a dictionary on each row of a dataframe column using a vectorized operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74955849/is-there-a-way-to-store-a-dictionary-on-each-row-of-a-dataframe-column-using-a-v)

User Panda Kim gets credit for solving the initial problem: https://stackoverflow.com/users/20430449/panda-kim

This is the solution using the answer that Panda Kim uses along with the final step needed that I pieced together.

First, we name a new column named for the key we'll use later outside of the wrapped dictionary and we'll get the values for the column by transposing the column name 'Account_Name__c' and it's corresponding value using the .T method, and setting it to a dictionary using to_dict()

```
final_insert['Account_Name__r'] = pd.Series(final_insert[['Account_Name__c']].T.to_dict())
```

the result:

```
ID      Date       Total_Transactions Account_Name__r
1234567 2022-12-21 1                  {'Account_Name__c':'a1234567'}
```

Finally, we then transform the entire dataframe to a dictionary or a json using either .to_dict() or .to_json()

```
final_insert = final_insert.to_dict(orient='records')
```

The result:

```
[{'ID': '1234567',
  'Date': '2022-12-21',
  'Total_Transactions': 1,
  'Amount': 235.00,
  'Account_Name__r': {'Account_Name__c':'a1234567'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data=[{'ID': '1234567',
  'Date': '2022-12-21',
  'Total_Transactions': 1,
  'Amount': 235.00,
  'Account_Name__c':'a1234567'},
{'ID': '2345678',
  'Date': '2022-13-21',
  'Total_Transactions': 2,
  'Amount': 300.50,
  'Account_Name__c':'a2345678'}]

df=pd.DataFrame(data)


df["Account_Name__r"]=df["Account_Name__c"].apply(lambda x: {"Account_Name__c":x})

df.drop(columns=["Account_Name__c"],inplace=True)

print(df.to_json(orient='records'))
```

Comment: You are misunderstanding the issue. We're transforming the data frame into a JSON, not the other way around. I know how to transform it into a JSON and get it close to the right format, but what I need is an additional nested dictionary. The examples are provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
out = df.to_dict(orient="records")

for d in out:
    d["ID"] = str(d["ID"])
    d["Account_Name__r"] = {"Account_Name__c": d.pop("Account_Name__c")}

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1234567",
        "Date": "2022-12-21",
        "Total_Transactions": 1,
        "Amount": 235.0,
        "Account_Name__r": {"Account_Name__c": "a1234567"},
    },
    {
        "ID": "2345678",
        "Date": "2022-13-21",
        "Total_Transactions": 2,
        "Amount": 300.5,
        "Account_Name__r": {"Account_Name__c": "a2345678"},
    },
]
```

Comment: In the sample provided here the data is small enough that introducing a loop would work, however I've been told in general that loops are not preferred. We'll be performing large post calls with this data. I use pandas to avoid using looping instead relying on the vector technology. A vector based solution would be preferable for this.

Comment: @TylerDavis First, do the perfomance testing. Is it slow? If yes, then try to optimize it. I'd guess the performance of this solution will be enough.

Comment: @AndrejKesley Ok, but we're not aiming for "enough," we're aiming for best practices and scalable solutions. I'd like to actually learn how to create the nested dataframe straight from pandas using vector transformations because that's going to be more scalable. I already knew how to make a forloop to achieve this. I'm modifying my question to be more clear on what I'm looking for.