# Is there a way to store a dictionary on each row of a dataframe column using a vectorized operation?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested, vectorization

I am attempting to next a dictionary inside of a dataframe.

here's an example of what I have:

```
x y z
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

here's an example of what I want:

```
x y z
1 2 {'z':3}
4 5 {'z':6}
7 8 {'z':9}
```

For this specific application, the whole point of using pandas is the vectorized operations that are scalable and efficient. Is it possible to transform that column into a column of dictionaries? I have attempted to use string concatenation, but then it is stored in pandas as a string and not a dict, and returns later with quotations around the dictionary because it is a string.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, you probably need a list comprehension or a simple apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {'x': {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 7}, 'y': {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 8}, 'z': {0: 3, 1: 6, 2: 9}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Code**

```
df['z'] = pd.Series(df[['z']].T.to_dict())
```

`df`

```
    x   y   z
0   1   2   {'z': 3}
1   4   5   {'z': 6}
2   7   8   {'z': 9}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've literally been researching this issue for days and have had so many people telling me to use for loops.